# Best way to cast a float to an int for arithmetic?

Tags: c#, casting

In C#, I am doing something like this:

```
float a = 4.0f;
float b = 84.5f;
int ans = a * b;
```

However, the compiler states that a cast is required to go from float -> int in assignment. Of course I could probably do this:

```
int ans = (int)a * (int)b;
```

But this is ugly and redundant. Is there a better way? I know in C++ I could do this:

```
int ans = int(a * b);
```

At least that looks a little better on the eyes. But I can't do this in C# it seems.

Comment: This really depends on what your final result.  What type of accuracy do you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should consider the need of your application before the look of the code.  Doing `float` math to `int`, is not something to be taken lightly.  The real question what are you looking for out of your final answer.

a is cast to 4, and b is cast to 84, which is the result of 336.  However if you cast it to an int after you do the math, the result is 338.

Is being off by 2 good enough for you?  Then you have to do

```
int ans = (int)a * (int)b;

// ans = 336
```

If you want 338 then you have to do

```
int ans = (int)(a * b);

// ans = 338
```

I would really consider the side effects about what you are doing.  Ideally you should have a policy for rounding the 2 floats before doing the math.  Remember casting to an int is just going to cut a decimal off.  So 84.9 becomes 84.  That could greatly change your final result.  You need to consider what is required in your application.

Comment: Thank you (and to everyone else) for the answers. What I really want is to truncate it *after* the multiplication, so the latter solution is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Put the `int` in parentheses as well.

```
int ans = (int)(a * b);
```

Comment: @SLaks what you call them depends on where you learned English.

Comment: This is a larger question than what looks good with the code.  Depending on when the cast will be done it will change the result.

Comment: @David, you are correct but his question specifically asked for the proper way to cast results. (I did upvote your answer for your thorough explanation though).

Answer (score 2):

```
 int ans = (int)a * (int)b; 

 int ans = (int)(a * b);
```

These two statements are not equivalent and will produce different results. In once case, you give up precision before the multiplication, in the other after the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Try `int ans = (int)(a * b);`

Answer (score 1):

```
int ans = (int)(a * b);
```